# Cannot paste into Intellij Idea from Vim

Tags: clipboard, ideavim, neovim

After yanking a text from Vim I cannot paste the clipboard content into Idea's editor window. I can, however, paste it in every other window (browser, terminal etc.).

The text becomes "pastable" (strangely) after I run command in a terminal:

`xclip -sel c -o | xclip -sel c`

or paste a line somewhere and copy it manually (Ctrl-C or mouse).

I have set options

`set clipboard+=unnamed, unnamedplus`

in both Idea (ideavim) and vim.

My system is Fedora 25. This problem manifested itself after I changed distribution, so maybe Wayland has something to do with it.

Comment: Same issue here. I use slackware 14.2 + KDE 4. And Wayland is not involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just want to share my situation. I've installed both `xclip` and `xsel` for neovim. It turns out that the contents piped to `xsel` was not recognized by intellij.

I uninstalled `xsel` and it works fine.